# proxy and retries for getaddrbyhost

Tags: python, proxy

This function keeps failing me, am I doing this right ? Is there another way to get a domain from an IP address?

```
def ip_to_domain(ip):

        for i in range(0,4):
                try:
                        domain = socket.gethostbyaddr(str(ip))
                        return domain
                except IOError:
                        continue
                else:
                        break
        else:
                return False
```

thanks for any advice you can give.

Comment: Rate limited? That would be extremely odd. I suspect you are discovering that synchronous calls are a bad idea and that DNS can take quite awhile to tell you that there's no answer.

Comment: really? I dont know what it was, but at some point after a lot of debugging and continuously rerunning the code, it started to choke on this one bit, so I assume Im doing something wrong, not sure what. digging the name ;) edit: what are 'synchronous calls' ? lots of them together ?

Comment: Synchronous calls are calls that wait for a result before continuing. Have you tried doing the lookups that choked completely independently?

Comment: ahh right I see. thankyou. no, I dont know how to do that yet Im just a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to trap `socket.herror`... Use something like this and check whether you get a None value in the relevant field...

```
import socket
def lookup(addr):
    """
    Example usage:
    name, alias, addresslist = lookup('4.2.2.2')
    """
    try:
        return socket.gethostbyaddr(addr)
    except socket.herror:
        return None, None, None
```

If you want to automagically lookup on a failure, do something like this...

```
import socket
import time
def relookup(addr):
    """
    Example usage:
    name, alias, addresslist = relookup('4.2.2.2')
    """
    attempts = 1
    while (attempts <= 3):
        try:
            return socket.gethostbyaddr(addr)
        except IOError, socket.herror:
            time.sleep(5)
            attempts += 1

    return None, None, None
```

Comment: hey Mike! :) thanks again dude, should i trap both those errors at the same time ie "except IOError,socket.herror:" or on different lines ? oh its me from yesterday cigar, but i changed the name cos it was|(nt) stupid|(enough) :)

Comment: You can use the same line for `IOError` and `socket.herror`, unless you want to print an error message to the console for the individual error that you got.

Comment: @colonwq, please see my edit with `relookup()`... that gives you multiple lookup attempts before returning None values...

Comment: oh nice. so i wasnt doing it right before then ? i didnt really understand what i was doing with that try business. i copied it off some post on here. the try, except stuff hasnt sunk in properly yet. why are there three nones. oh right, for each iteration ? thankyou sah!

Comment: @colonwq, three `None` values represent the arguments returned by `socket.gethostbyaddr()`... the function gives you several result values from a single call (although many people only use it for the name)